# node js migration is so slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, migration, sequelize.js

I wanted to know what is the issue with my migration code below why is that it is so slow , the migration just keeps loading , any concern with my implementation guys ? is array of promises a solution to this ?

#the issue is on this block

```
 for (let i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
        const prefix = Date.now().toString();
        const fileParts = documents[i].filename.split('.');
        const finalname = `${fileParts[0]}-${prefix}.${fileParts[1]}`;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
        await queryInterface.sequelize.query(`UPDATE ${EmployeeDocumentsModel.tableName} SET filename='${finalname}' WHERE id=${documents[i].id};`, { transaction });
      }
```

#Code

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface) => {
    const transaction = await queryInterface.sequelize.transaction();
    try {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
      const documents = await sequelizeClient.query(
        `SELECT id, filename, COUNT(filename) FROM ${EmployeeDocumentsModel.tableName} GROUP BY filename
      HAVING COUNT(filename) > 1;`,
        { type: QueryTypes.SELECT },
      );

      // eslint-disable-next-line no-plusplus
      for (let i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
        const prefix = Date.now().toString();
        const fileParts = documents[i].filename.split('.');
        const finalname = `${fileParts[0]}-${prefix}.${fileParts[1]}`;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
        await queryInterface.sequelize.query(`UPDATE ${EmployeeDocumentsModel.tableName} SET filename='${finalname}' WHERE id=${documents[i].id};`, { transaction });
      }

      // eslint-disable-next-line no-return-assign

      await queryInterface.addConstraint(
        EmployeeDocumentsModel.tableName,
        ['employeeId', 'filename'],
        {
          type: 'unique',
          name: 'composite_employee_filename',
        },
        {
          transaction,
        },
      );
      await transaction.commit();
    } catch (err) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(err);
      await transaction.rollback();
      throw err;
    }
    return true;
  },
```

Comment: how many documents do you process?

Comment: I think it is just around 300 @Anatoly

Comment: do you have some suggestion with my implementation ? is there part of my code that made it slow or an error ?

Comment: 399 simple updates wouldn't be an issue. Did you measure a total time of `for` loop?

Comment: not really sure cause the migration just keep loading when i remove that block then it continue , so the issue is within that loop

Comment: try to output to console consumed time for each iteration.